# Function for PowerShell command with elevated rights and need to skip confirmation

Tags: powershell

To disable a device via PS the following code can be used (skipping the confirmation dialog), it needs to run in an elevated CLI:

```
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceID "BTHENUM\DEV_123\1&23E&0&BLUETOOTHDEVICE_001123" -confirm:$false
```

I created a Function that should run the command on a new elevated CLI but for some reason, it does not work on the above command:

```
Function turnoff { Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList { Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceID "BTHENUM\DEV_123\1&23E&0&BLUETOOTHDEVICE_001123" -confirm:$false } -verb RunAs }
```

The new CLI briefly opens but closes again and the command is not executed. I haven't found the problem yet, any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The `ArgumentsList` should be a string or an array of strings defining the **parameters**. Your code defines a **scriptblock**

Comment: @Theo I used it in the same manner to stop a process `Function killtabtip { Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList { Stop-Process -processname tabtip } -verb RunAs }` which works fine, the only difference I see are the quotation marks. Do they cause the problem?

Comment: Use the `PowerShell -NoExit` parameter to check for any errors.

Comment: @iRon ok, thanks, then I think, I will have to get rid of the scriptblock, or do you know how add the -NoExit and keep the scriptblock? Also I did some testing and noticed if and error occurs the windows closes anyway (despite the -NoExit parameter working before introducing the error)

Comment: As commented by @Theo, the [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `[[-ArgumentList] <String[]>]` parameter requires a **string array**. Meaning that your scriptblock is conveniently type casted to a string anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Pass the command to be executed by the elevated `powershell.exe` *as a single string* to `Start-Process -ArgumentList` - do *not* use a script block (`{ ... }`).
- Escape any `"` characters that are part of the command passed to `powershell.exe`'s (implied) `-Command` (`-c`) parameter  as `\"`

Read on for an explanation; solution is at the bottom.

---

As noted in the comments, **you can *get away* with passing a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) to [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)' `-ArgumentList` parameter**, because it is automatically converted to a *string* (the parameter is `[string[]]`-typed and therefore accepts one or more (an array of) strings), but **it is *ill-advised***:

- It is conceptually problematic, because it may mislead you to think that you can use regular PowerShell syntax inside the script block and that you can reference *variables* in it.
- In fact, the script block stringifies to its *verbatim* content (without the `{` and `}`, which means that variable values can *not* be referenced.

---

**You should pass a *single string*** to begin with:

- Note: While passing an *array* of arguments may be conceptually appealing, a long-standing bug that won't be fixed in the interest of backward compatibility - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576)  - makes it preferable to **encode *all* arguments in a *single* string, using *escaped* embedded quoting as necessary**.
- If you need to embed variable references or expressions in the string, i.e. if you need *string interpolation*, choose an [*expandable* (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), otherwise use a [*verbatim* (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)

  - To **make dealing with *embedded* quotes easier**, you can use the **[here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) variants** of these string literals (as shown below).

---

The (possibly expanded) single string you pass to `-ArgumentList` is copied verbatim to the command line used behind the scenes for actual invocation, so **you need to make sure that you satisfy the command-line syntax requirements of the target application**.

Since you happen to be calling the **Windows PowerShell CLI, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**, which by default interprets positional arguments as targeting the **`-Command`  (`-c`) parameter**,<sup>[1]</sup> **special quoting requirements apply:**

- During initial command-line parsing, PowerShell considers *unescaped* `"` characters to have syntactic function *on the command line only*, and *strips* them.

  - In order **to pass `"` characters that should be retained *as part of the PowerShell command to execute***, you must **escape them as `\"`** (sic).
- After stripping unescaped `"` and converting escaped ones (`\"`) to *verbatim* ones (`"`), the resulting arguments are joined with spaces and the resulting string is then executed as PowerShell code.

To put it all together, using a verbatim here-string (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`), since no expansion (string interpolation) is needed:

```bash
Function turnoff { 

  # Note the need to escape the embedded " as \" for the sake of powershell.exe
  Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList @'
    -c Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceID \"BTHENUM\DEV_123\1&23E&0&BLUETOOTHDEVICE_001123\" -confirm:$false
'@ # Note: Delimiter must be *at the very start* of the line.

}
```

Note:

- For full robustness, namely to avoid potential whitespace normalization, the *entire* `-c` (`-Command`) argument should be enclosed in (syntactic, unescaped) `"..."`. In the interest of brevity I've omitted that above, as it isn't strictly necessary here.
- To troubleshoot the call, place `-NoExit` before `-c` in order to keep the elevated session open after the command finishes executing.

---

<sup>[1] Caveat: [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI, now defaults to `-File`, so you'll *always* need to use `-Command` or `-c` explicitly there to pass commands.</sup>